# RegEx in Notepad++ to find and replace strings

Tags: regex, string, replace, find, notepad++

I'm trying to find and replace strings using RegEx on Notepad++, but cannot identify the right expression to do it:

Here is the data:

```
TRAIN-II
TRAIN
TRAIN-I
AIRPLANE-II
AIRPLANE
AIRPLANE-I
SHIP-II
SHIP
SHIP-I
```

Well, I want to keep only the string which has "-II" as suffix. In simpler words, I want to retain only:

```
TRAIN-II
AIRPLANE-II
SHIP-II
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(?<!-II)(?:\R|\Z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?<!-II)      # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't -II before the following
  (?:\R|\Z)     # non capture group, any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n) or end of file
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to mark the lines, then remove unmarked lines.

Open the search window and then the "Mark" tab.
Enter `-II$` into the "Find what" box. Select "Regular expressions". Select "Match case" if the "II" must be in upper case. Select "Bookmark line". Click on "Mark all". Expect to see the wanted lines marked with a blue circle. Use menu => Search => Bookmark => Remove unmarked lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the procedure is right, but I need a regular expression.

Comment: This has a regular expression. Please explain what you want more clearly.

Comment: I wanted a regular expression like `.*-I.*\r?\n` which, if placed on the Search and Replace section of Notepad++ will remove the unwanted strings in a single step.

Comment: Then please edit the question to explain that. Also add what you have tried, and describe what it did and why it was not as you wanted.

Comment: Please also explain why using the Mark facility is not suitable.

Comment: Marking will not suffice my needs and it's purely my project requirement.